# MIME type for WP8 AET

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, in-house-distribution

I am looking for the Mime type for an aetx file.

This file is used when distributing a windows phone 8 application in house. a user downloads and installs this to their phone. 
But, when you download this file the phone does not give the option to install this enrollment token.
I can only guess the web server is not set to the correct MIME type so the phone is responding appropriately.

my google skills have failed me on the occasion and the microsoft documentation is... sparse on this subject.

thanks for any help.

Martyn

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally found it. in the aet.xml file that's created when you generate one of these tokens you can see its an x509 certificate file.

So, the mime type is:

"application/c-x509-ca-cert"

So you can host this on a secure site and then set the mime type for your users to download, hopefully it saves someone else some time.

Comment: This works only on Windows Phone 8, does'nt seem to work on Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 2):

While Martin's answer is correct for Windows Phone 8.0, it won't work for Windows Phone 8.1.

If you use **"application/c-x509-ca-cert"** with 8.1, the **.aetx** file is transformed to **.cer** and you get the error **0x8028a001** *"Your phone couldn't add one or more certificates because the certificate file might be unsupported or corrupt ..."*.

The correct type for 8.1 is **"application/octet-stream"**. Same mime-type used when you send the token as attachment in an email.

But with **"application/octet-stream"**, WindowPhone 8.0 doesn't see the aetx file as token and displays its content to the user.

The solution is to use a servlet (or equivalent if you're not using java) to set the mime type dynamically.